# SQL server view return different results in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-view

I have a sql view in SQl server:

```
SELECT        dbo.job.idJob, SUM(dbo.tracking.iQty) AS TotalOrdered, dbo.tracking.idProduct
FROM            dbo.tracking INNER JOIN
                         dbo.job ON dbo.tracking.idJob = dbo.job.idJob
GROUP BY dbo.tracking.idAction, dbo.tracking.idProduct, dbo.job.idJob
```

In SQL Server it returns:

```
idJob       TotalOrdered idProduct
----------- ------------ -----------
5000        150          9
5000        75           18
5006        20           3
```

### THE PROBLEM:

When I access this view through Entity Framework 6 in a WPF 4.5 project it returns different results.  I add the view to the edmx file and then call the view in the following way:

```
Public Function GetTracking_Ordered(idJob As Integer) As Collection(Of vw_Tracking_Ordered) Implements ITrackingDataService.GetTracking_Ordered
            Try
                Using context = _ModelService.NewContext

                    Dim trackingList = (From recs In context.vw_Tracking_Ordered Where recs.idJob = idJob Select recs).ToList
                    Return New Collection(Of vw_Tracking_Ordered)(trackingList)

                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
```

The following are the results:

```
idJob       TotalOrdered idProduct
----------- ------------ -----------
5000        150          9
5000        75           9
5006        20           3
```

NOTICE the idProduct for the 5000 job are now both 9 instead of 9 and 18.

### QUESTION:

Can anyone help me debug why this result changes from SQL server to Entity Framework?

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that your `View` in the `.edmx` file has a **Primary Key** assigned. If it hasn't, add the proper `entity key` yourself using the edmx designer. I this case you may want to include columns `idJob` and `idProduct` in your entity key.

Read here also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd163156(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I had a primary key for just the job.  I added entity key = true to the productId column as well in the edmx designer and it works now.  Thanks, although I do not understand why this was needed?

Comment: I'm not sure, it happened to me also and it was super annoying. I **think** that what you're really returning from the view is a unique set of `idJob+idProduct`. And with the wrong Entity Key (`jobId` only), `EF` is not able to return correctly some other fields, like `idProduct`. It looks like he's taking the first occurence of your `idProduct`, repeating it for every job. What it's strange to me is that `TotalOrdered` looks fine...

Comment: Does this mean, if we have a SQL Heap (a table without clustered index) we cannot use entity framework to retrieve data (correctly)?

Comment: I'm happy that I found this answer. Uff, I was struggled for 2 days having exactly the same issue mapping a sql view with entity framework 6. I changed my view to avoid returning null values and it worked! thanks every one for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate @Vland, his answer helped to understand the problem is about missing key! So I solved to problem from the root!
I know this is not a best practice, but these steps solved mine!

1. I added a row to my view by ROW_NUMBER()

   select
   ROW_NUMBER() over(order by FieldA asc) as id, FieldA, FieldB
   from  MyView

you can put the above code inside your view

I have a rowNumber column for indexing the view rows

2. At visual studio, I updated the model in my .edmx diagram and added my new view
3. Check if id column is not signed as Key, right click on id field an click "Entity Key"
   remember to uncheck other columns if they are key sign.
4. rebuild & lunch the project, you can see the result is correct as you can see in sql server